# Some features of Xtext-based editor don't work on files outside a project

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtext

I've written an Xtext-based plugin which works well when I open files inside one of the projects in my workspace; however, when I open a file outside the workspace (via File -> Open File...), some of the features don't work properly:

- I get syntax coloring but I don't get syntax errors.
- Quickfix options don't work, probably because `context.getXtextDocument()` returns `null` and I rely on it for my quickfix proposals.

There might be other things I'm missing, but most other features, such as content assist, definitions-on-hover, occurrence marking etc., work fine.

**Is there a way I could make workspace-external source files behave the same as internal files?** Alternatively, is there a workaround which will enable me to "trick" Xtext, somehow convincing it that the file is internal to the current project, for example by programmatically creating a link to it from the project?

[This is a related question about the behavior with a workspace-external file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239458/cannot-open-workspace-external-file-in-xtext-based-plugin), however I succeed in opening these files just fine, it's just that some features are not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long a I know, currently there are no way to just make workspace-external source files behave the same as internal files.

Here is the workaround for broken validation:

- In xxx.ui plugin, XxxUiModule.java add

  ```
  public Class<? extends IResourceForEditorInputFactory> bindIResourceForEditorInputFactory() {
      return MyJavaClassPathResourceForIEditorInputFactory.class;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<? extends IXtextEditorCallback> bindIXtextEditorCallback() {
      return MyNatureAddingEditorCallback.class;
  }
  ```
- Create MyJavaClassPathResourceForIEditorInputFactory.java

  ```
  // Reenable validation
  public class MyJavaClassPathResourceForIEditorInputFactory extends JavaClassPathResourceForIEditorInputFactory {

      @Override
      protected Resource createResource(java.net.URI uri) {
          XtextResource resource = (XtextResource) super.createResource(uri);
          resource.setValidationDisabled(false);
          return resource;
      }
  }
  ```
- Create MyNatureAddingEditorCallback.java

  ```
  // With reenabled validation the syntax validation starts to work only after the first change made
  // Run the validation manually to show the syntax errors straight away
  // - CheckMode.ALL below should be probably changed to something else to improve the performance
  public class MyNatureAddingEditorCallback extends NatureAddingEditorCallback {
      @Inject
      private IResourceValidator resourceValidator;
      @Inject 
      private MarkerCreator markerCreator;
      @Inject
      private MarkerTypeProvider markerTypeProvider;
      @Inject
      private IssueResolutionProvider issueResolutionProvider;

      @Override
      public void afterCreatePartControl(XtextEditor editor) {
          super.afterCreatePartControl(editor);
          validate(editor);
      }

      private void validate(XtextEditor xtextEditor) {
          if (xtextEditor == null) {
              return;
          }
          if (xtextEditor.getInternalSourceViewer() == null) {
              return;
          }
          IValidationIssueProcessor issueProcessor;
          IXtextDocument xtextDocument = xtextEditor.getDocument();
          IResource resource = xtextEditor.getResource();
          if(resource != null)
              issueProcessor = new MarkerIssueProcessor(resource, markerCreator, markerTypeProvider);
          else
              issueProcessor = new AnnotationIssueProcessor(xtextDocument, xtextEditor.getInternalSourceViewer().getAnnotationModel(), issueResolutionProvider);
          ValidationJob validationJob = new ValidationJob(resourceValidator, xtextDocument, issueProcessor,
                  CheckMode.ALL); // Consider changing the CheckMode here
          validationJob.schedule();
      }
  }
  ```

See also the corresponding bug report:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388399